# Struggling to set up "network" drives on home p.c. to mimic work environment for software development

Tags: networking, windows-10

I want to mimic my work computer so I can develop with reference to my network drives for my Windows 10 computer at home.

I want S:\ drive to point to some local drive on my computer.

I am following directions to the letter when attempting to create homegroup for windows 10.

When I type HomeGroup under search, I don't see any option, as shown in article below.

Any ideas?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17145/windows-homegroup-from-start-to-finish

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple.
Set up drive partitions.
Much simpler and more reliable...

Answer (score 0):

folks, this is a good question, and I struggled with it.
i don't appreciate the negative points.
here is the answer.

To do what I need to do, you have to go to file explorer, and under sharing tab, i was able to share with everyone (the folder).

Then, in my mappping, i have to refer to \\ComputerName\ShareName.

They keep changing the way things work from one windows to the next....